# Not able to use Shell32.dll in .Net 4.0 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, com-interop, shell32

I have C# VS 2010 project which uses Shell32.dll. Shell32.dll is used for creating zip file.
The machine is Win7 64-bit. The projects compile and runs fine when .net target version is 2.0 or 3.5.
However changing it to 4.0 results in compilation failure. I tried by removing & adding refernce to Shell32.dll again and changing the target platform as X86. But still failed to compile.
Looking for reason & resolution.

Update: I tried creating new project and added reference to Shell32.dll. This time I refered the dll from C:\Windows\SysWOW64 insted of C:\Windows\System32. Now this time it compiled fine. But I am not sure if this project will run on 32-bit windows and XP and other versions.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by adding a reference to shell32? That is a native dll, you can't directly reference it from a C# project, you would use pInvoke to call methods it exports but you don't need a reference in your project.

Ryan

Comment: Visual Studio takes care of creating interop wrapper for the dll.